# How to draw electric circuits in LaTeX?

Tags: circuitikz

[image]

I need to do this in LaTeX, can someone help me, please?

This is what I have so far..... I'm having problems to identify, how to connect a resistor in the middle of a line coming from `(opamp .-)`
if you identify the first opamp from the left, you can see it

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[free-standing-units]{siunitx}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw (0,0) node[op amp] (opamp) {}
(opamp.+) node[left, anchor=north] {$3$} to [R] (-5,-0.5)
(opamp.-) node[left] {$2$} to [short,*-] ++(0,4) to [short,*-] ++(0,2) to [R={$R1$}](18,6.5) {}
(opamp.out) node[right, anchor=north] {$6$} to (1.5,0) to [R={$R1$}](4,0) {}
(opamp.up) --++(0,1.5) node[anchor=east, *-o]{\textnormal{-Vcc}} (-0.2,1.3) node[anchor=east]{\textnormal{4}}
(opamp.down) --++(0,-1.5) node[anchor=west, *-o]{\textnormal{Vcc}} (0.2,-1.3) node[anchor=west]{\textnormal{7}};

\draw (8,0) node [op amp] {};

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: my result so far]

also need to connect Resistor `R1` coming from `(opamp.out)` to `(opamp.-)`

Comment: Welcome to the site.  What have you tried so far?  It is customary to show code of your current efforts.  Questions of the "do this for me" variety are frowned upon.

Comment: LaTeX offers the package `circuitikz` which helps you to draw electrical or electronical curcuits.

Answer (score 1):

Note, you can also use relative positioning using ++(x,y).

```
\documentclass{standalone}    
\usepackage[free-standing-units]{siunitx}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw (0,0) node[op amp] (opamp) {}
(opamp.+) node[left, anchor=north] {$3$} to [R] (-5,-0.5)
(opamp.-) node[left] {$2$} to [short,*-] ++(0,4) to [short,*-] ++(0,2) to [R={$R1$}](18,6.5) {}
(opamp.out) node[right, anchor=north] {$6$} to (1.5,0) to [R={$R1$},*-*](4,0) {};
(opamp.up) --++(0,1.5) node[anchor=east, *-o]{\textnormal{-Vcc}} (-0.2,1.3) node[anchor=east]{\textnormal{4}}
(opamp.down) --++(0,-1.5) node[anchor=west, *-o]{\textnormal{Vcc}} (0.2,-1.3) node[anchor=west]{\textnormal{7}};
\draw (4,0) node [op amp,anchor=-] {};

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]